# Changing Firebase email address verification limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My app's email address verification using firebase (sendEmailVerification) has about 1 minute per request per user limit.

Is there any way to lessen this built in limit to about 20 seconds without using external provider?

While sending more than one request in a short time I get:

**FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/too-many-requests)**